# Php - What's wrong with this FTP setup?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to connect via FTP to a client on my network using PHP:

```
$fileName = "jobfiles/jobfile-fileName.txt"; //local file created on web sever     
$ftp_host = "7PD01-2012.networkname.local"; //networked client 
// trying to transfer to shared folder PTBurnJobs
$ftp_user_name = "ryan@7PD01-2012.networkname.local";
$ftp_user_pass = "***"; //password is correct
$connect_it = ftp_connect($ftp_host);
$login_result = ftp_login($connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$remote_file = "BurnJob.jrq";
$local_file = $fileName;
ftp_put($connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

I am not getting this error: 
ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/CDprinter/processor.php on line 145

So I am connecting but not authenicated?